# Search for Excel data in json and replace

Tags: python, excel

There is a dictionary that looks like this

```
[
    {
        "Name": Name1,
        "Price": "151",
        "Teg": "",
        "Specifications": {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": ID1,
        "Name": Name1,
        "Price": "151",
        "Teg": "",
        "Specifications": {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3"
        }
    },
]
```

And Excel table:

| New_Name | Article | Code | Provider | Price | currency | Price+currency | Company | Old_name |

| NewName1 | NewName1 | 233 | Provider1 | 333 | USD | 333 USD | Company1 | OldName1 |

Open the excel file and compare the 2 fields "New name" and "Article", if the values in these fields are equal, then go to json and find the necessary block by the value from the "Article" field of the Excel file. In the found json block, we look for the string "Name" and replace the value from the "Old_name" field of the Excel file in it.

My Code:

```
import json
import pandas


def get_data_excel():
    data = pandas.read_excel(
        r"C:\Users\user1\PycharmProjects\project1\total.xls",
        usecols=["New_Name", "Old_name "]
    )
    df = pandas.DataFrame(data).fillna(0)
    df = df.values

    new_items = []
    for item in df:

        item_list = item.tolist()

        temp_list = []
        for i in item_list:
            if type(i) == int:
                temp_list.append(i)
                continue
            elif type(i) == float:
                temp_list.append(i)
                continue
            else:
                i = i.strip()
                temp_list.append(i)

        new_items.append(temp_list)
    return new_items


def search_item():

    with open("_final_result_v2.json", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        items = json.load(file)

    excel_data_list = get_data_excel()

    for item in items:
        item_name = item["New_Name"]

        for i in excel_data_list:
            if item_name != i[0] in i:
                item["New_Name"] = i[1]
            else:
                pass

    print(items)

    with open("result111.json", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        json.dump(excel_data_list, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_data_excel()
    search_item()
```

I can't figure out where to embed the search block.